# .getcurrentrow (DCIteratorBinding) is returning null after an hour

Tags: nullpointerexception, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am new in ADF (EJB/JPA not Business Component), when the user is using our new app developed on jdeveloper "12.2.1.2.0", after an hour of activity, system is loosing the current record. To note that the object lost is the parent object.

I tried to change the session-timeout (knowing that it will affect the inactivity time).

```
public List<SelectItem> getSProvMasterSelectItemList(){
   List<SelectItem> sProvMasterSelectItemList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
   DCIteratorBinding lBinding = ADFUtils.findIterator("pByIdIterator");/*After 1 hour I am able to get lBinding is not null*/ 
   Row pRow = lBinding.getCurrentRow();/*But lBinding.getCurrentRow() is null*/
   DCDataRow objRow = (DCDataRow) pRow;
   Prov prov = (Prov) objRow.getDataProvider();
   if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(prov)){
      String code = prov.getCode(); 
      if (StringUtils.isEmpty(code)){
         return sProvMasterSelectItemList;
      }else{
         List<Lov> mProvList = getSessionEJBBean().getProvFindMasterProv(code);
         sProvMasterSelectItemList.add(new SelectItem(null," "));
         for (Lov pMaster:mProvList) {
            sProvMasterSelectItemList.add(new SelectItem(pMaster.getId(),pMaster.getDescription()));
                }
      }
   }
return sProvMasterSelectItemList ;
}
```

I expect to be able to read the current record at any time, specially that it is the master block, and one record is available.

Answer (score 1):

This look like a classic issue of misconfigured Application Module.

**Cause :** Your application module is timing out and releasing it's transaction before the official adfc-config timeout value.

**To Fix :** 
Go to the application module containing this VO > Configuration > Edit the default > **Modify Idle Instance Timeout** to be the same as your adf session timeout (Take time to validate the other configuration aswell)

Comment: Dear Cedric, mentioned solution is valid for EJB/JPA (since we are not using business component). Thank you